# Different fonts inside a label

Tags: javascript, html, css, mxml

If I have labels such as "1234B", "5678M"... How can I change this label so the letter at the end is smaller size than the size of numbers?

Answer (score 1):

```
<p>1234<span class="smaller">B</span></p>

.smaller {
    font-size: 5px;
}
```

Comment: `5px` might be an overkill :-)

Comment: @LittleBigBot I meant, like, `0.9em` :-)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to use the `small` element (which is still allowed in HTML5, though with contrived “semantics”, but to browsers it still means just smaller font size):

```
1234<small>B</small>
```

You can then use CSS to tune the font size reduction, e.g. with

```
small { font-size: 80%; }
```

However, this produces typographically bad results, since different font size implies different stroke width, so the letters will look thinner, too, in addition to being smaller. In typography, one would probably use small-caps glyphs of the font instead (though in typography, one would normally rather try and make digits and letters match in size, rather than unmatch!). This is in principle possible on web pages too (using `font-feature-settings: "smcp"`, with prefixes), though still rare, and it requires a font that has such glyphs available (like Calibri, Cambria, or Palatino Linotype).

Comment: Ok, but this labels are all different and I don't know if it has that letter at the end, it can be without it too. And I have a lot of them, is there a way, to check if the last letter is a letter, if yes, make it smaller, if not, nothing changed.
I need a dynamic function for this.

Comment: Then you need a *function*, in a server-side or client-side programming language, that inserts the `small` markup or some other suitable markup. HTML and CSS have no functions (just some functional notations), and there is no CSS selector for “last letter”.

Comment: @laura.graham you will need at least javascript to do something like that.

Comment: Ok, I knew that, but how can I insert that "small" markup? Can you write me java script function that does this?

Answer (score 0):

watson has it.............. but let me think **CMS thinking**......if you just want to lowercase the only letter and the numbers stay put you can do this:

HTML:

```
 <div style="text-transform: lowercase;">3529M</div>
```

or

```
<div class="lowMe">3529M</div>
<div class="lowMe">5546D</div>
```

CSS:

```
.lowMe {text-transform: lowercase}
```

else I would just do span as it was mentioned...